# Update with left join in Eloquent Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update with left join doing this

```php
    CurrencyShop::from('ps_currency_shop')->leftJoin('ps_currency', 'ps_currency.id_currency', '=', 'ps_currency_shop.id_currency')
    ->where('ps_currency.conversion_rate', 2)
    ->update(['ps_currency_shop.conversion_rate' => \DB::raw('ps_currency.conversion_rate')]);
    dump(DB::connection('mysql_remote')->getQueryLog());
```

the query log looks fine. BUT IS NOT UPDATING :((( someone with the same issue, please
laravel version 5.6

Comment: wats the logged query in dump() ?

Comment: "query" => "update `ps_currency_shop` left join `ps_currency` on `ps_currency`.`id_currency` = `ps_currency_shop`.`id_currency` set `ps_currency_shop`.`conversion_rate` = ps_currency.conversion_rate where `ps_currency`.`id_currency` = ?"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "ps_currency_shop.id_currency"
    ]

Comment: the problem is in the where,

Answer (score 1):

WhereRaw solved the problem

```php
->whereRaw('ps_currency.id_currency', 'ps_currency_shop.id_currency')
```